# Reverse a string using no variables while using recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

How can you reverse a string using recursion following the constraints mentioned in the function

```
string reverse_recurse(string forward) { // recursive
// Constraints: No loops allowed; no static local or global variables.
// Your new code goes here...
return ""; 
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken but your _question_ is essentially just the pasted code at the bottom? The 3 lines that says "your new code goes here", as the rest of the text above and the code above isn't relevant.

Comment: The problem itself is fairly interesting, but you could make the question here much better by explaining what you need to do (more or less says so in the title), and your attempts at the problem. They needn't be code attempts, you could just state that you tried _x_ but realised you'd need a variable or something

Comment: They probably want you to do something like swap elements `0` and `n-1`, then recurse and swap `1` and `n-2` and so on. Your base case is `n/2`. You can probably start in the middle and work outwards, too.

Comment: Reverse a string using recursion with the constraints mentioned in the second function.

Comment: After the latest edit, there is no question at all.

Comment: Fine I'll add "How can you"....

Comment: `return std::string(forward.rbegin(), forward.rend());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick implementation of the second approach described in Robᵩ's answer. Basically, return the last element of the string concatenated with the reverse of the other elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse_string(std::string a_string) {
    return
      a_string.length() > 0 ?
        a_string.back()
          + reverse_string(a_string.substr(0, a_string.length() - 1)) :
        std::string();
}

int main() {
    std::string a_string = "live on time , emit no evil";

    std::cout << a_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << reverse_string(a_string) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For any recursion problem, we need 1) a single step that gets us closer to a solution, 2) a recursive call on a smaller problem, and 3) a base case from which we can return immediately.

I propose that the single step is to swap the first and final characters, while passing all of the interior characters to the recursive call.

```
def reverse_recurse(forward):
    return forward[last] + 
           reverse_recurse(forward[second .. one_before_last]) +
           forward[0]
```

So, `reverse_recurse("abcd")` returns `d + reverse_recurse(bc) + a`.

Our base case should involve no work at all. If the original string has an even number of characters, then the base case is when the passed-in `forward` is the empty string. If the original string has an odd number of characters, the base case is when the passing-in `forward` has a single character (the middle character from the original string).

```
def reverse_recurse(forward):
    if forward.len() is 0 or 1:
        return forward
    return forward[last] + 
           reverse_recurse(forward[second .. one_before_last]) +
           forward[0]
```

If you understand what I've proposed, you can implement it in C++. (Hint: `std::string::substr()` exists.)

#### EDIT 1

In comments, SergeyA suggests an easier alternative. The single step is to isolate the final character and the recursive call is on the all-but-the-last string:

```
def reverse_recurse(forward):
    if forward.len() is 0 or 1:
        return forward
    return forward[last] + 
           reverse_recurse(forward[first .. one_before_last])
```

#### EDIT 2

Now, since the homework deadline is passed, here is my implementation.

```
string reverse_recurse(string forward) {
    if (forward.size() == 0)
        return forward;
    return reverse_recurse(forward.substr(1)) + forward.substr(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to swap? Seems like simply 'last charcter' + reverse(substring) should work?

Comment: No valid reason. Yes, I believe that works and is easier to conceive.

Comment: I really like the way you give python code :) - I assume, this is to prevent copy-paste?

Comment: I figured pseudo code would at least preserve some of the educational value of OP's homework. Sadly, all of my pseudo-code looks like Python.